# getting out early as the only new hire during a merger, and no one else wants my job

Tags: interviewing, work-environment, resignation, new-hires

I posted a few days ago about wanting to quit my new job due to failure to clarify some key points of the position during the interview process and whether or not leaving after a month or so will reflect poorly on me and my referral. Inability to pursue my other priorities not withstanding, in the past few days I've come to learn that there were several red flags:

- The company was just bought out, which I knew going in, but I was told my department was not affected and it turns out it actually is, now
- The man who hired me is one of the people who was offered early retirement (forced out after 25 years?) in the merger/restructuring process, which means that after Christmas nobody actually really knows who our immediate supervisor is
- Three more offers were just made, and all three were turned down
- Nobody I work with has been with the company longer than about 9 months, and most people move on within a year

I've already started covertly applying elsewhere with no plans to list this on my resume unless the search takes a while, as it's pretty obvious that I walked into a gigantic mess. I'm not sure if I was lied to or if I was just clueless, but knowing this now, and wanting to minimize negative consequences all around, what should I be saying to people about why I left IF it gets out that I worked there? My current employment, as far as my resume is concerned, is just my freelancing. (and obviously my facebook friends know I have a new job, but that's a private page)

I have been reading through other questions, but is there anything else I ought to be doing now that things are coming out of the woodwork? These are lofty things that are all very new for me.

Comment: What do you mean by "three more offers were just made"? Anyway, if you feel that you were mislead then that's a perfectly valid reason to jump ship. Your friend should understand that the situation seemed unstable - just don't make getting a new job about ***you***. Make it about the company: that they did not say that you would be forced to work the full weekend every weekend, and that so many people being forced out/quitting made you feel uncomfortable. That's pretty reasonable.

Comment: I'm a little uncertain about your post and what you are asking.  You have identified a number of clear indicators that things look very bleak in your current position, and as such you are wisely searching elsewhere.  I don't understand your statement "Three more offers were just made, and all three were turned down".  If you find a position elsewhere, you should take it--even if it's just an "Escape Plan" or job you take now without any intention of remaining long term.

Comment: Three more offers were just made = they still need staff, they offered the job to three people and all of them said no. I don't know if that means three separate people or one position was turned down 3 separate times.

Comment: @edubs - yea, just get out. Don't list it on your resume, but if you know someone's going to run a background check then you may want to mention that you had that job, but that due to circumstances surrounding the merger you didn't feel comfortable sticking around.

Comment: Do you think you are "on the way out" regardless? Is there any way you could turn a situation around and come out smelling of roses so to speak (and could talk about that in interviews etc)?

Comment: I'm on the way out by choice because the job is not in the industry i wish to work in and doesn't give me much, if any, leeway to work toward other goals, and because the hours are restrictive, not because I fear I'll be fired. I realize taking the job was a mistake, but that is how you learn

Comment: What's the scope of the merger? A larger company swallowing up yours in which case could there be more opportunities in the new year? If not, be open about it not being a good fit as the company's direction and yours aren't aligned which you have now realised etc... I'm inclined to say give the buying company a chance if possible and in a few months you will be much better placed to put that in context in an interview at worst. Or maybe they will surprise you?

Comment: @user43744 - gigantic media conglomerate with largely negative reputation just bought my much older and beloved organization for several hundred billion. People claim the restructuring has nothing to do with the merger, but, well. I work in the part the public sees, hence the apparent need for EVERYONE being there all the time, and also probably not in a department that would see many opportunities for growth beyond making me full time, which is even MORE restrictive for me.

Comment: But you don't have another question.  Did you just delete and repost?  You should update the existing question.

Answer (score 9):

Dwoz is right, "the circumstances in which I've been hired are no more" is an excellent argument.

Though I'd like to add, you are living interesting times. In your place I'd stay a few more month to learn how it happens. Maybe there will be opportunities for you. Though the most likely is no, there will be no place for you. But stay alert. At worst, you'll learn a lot of things on the human side.

Of course, making your resume & looking for an exit door is mandatory, but don't be closed to your current firm. When everything moves, there may be opportunities.

Answer (score 7):

There's no taint on you for a situation like this.  In interviews you say that department changes occurring as you walked in the door created a new situation and new priorities, in which it was clear you didn't feel the job was a good fit.

Comment: On this note, is there reason to exclude the work from the resume?

Comment: @jpmc26 Maybe; remember the resume predates interviews, so predates the opportunity to explain.